# Visual Studio skips unit tests on my machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, mstest

Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.2) (Windows). The solution I work on have multiple unit test projects (MSTest) and I was able to run them using both VS built-in test runner as well as Resharper test runner.

Recently, I've noticed that Resharper stopped recognizing these projects as unit test projects and I'm unable to run them through this extension. I've tried to use built-in VS test runner. It seems to properly discover unit tests, but skips all of them immediately every time I try to run them. There is no message provided. Debugging doesn't work either.

I'm the only one in my team who has this problem - the other colleagues who work on the same code base are able to run the tests. Below the list of things I've tried already:

- Restarting my PC :).
- Running Visual Studio as Administrator.
- Disabling and removing Resharper extension (along with all its files
  in AppData / Program Files) - didn’t help. Reinstalling Visual Studio
  2019 (removed all of the files in AppData / ProgramFiles / Temp
  before installation) without Resharper extension - didn’t help.
- Completely removing /bin/ and rebuilding the solution - didn’t help.
- Completely removing entire repository and cloning it again to new
  location - didn’t help.

Interestingly enough, when I setup a new solution with MSTest project, I can run the tests without problems.

Has anybody here has had the same problem and was able to fix it?

Comment: Maybe .editorconfig have any effect?

Comment: No, it's not it. If it was, it would affect all who works on the same repository, wouldn't it?

Comment: .editorconfig is contained in gitignore?

Comment: I'll see what I can find, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio and removing the .vs folder. That helps me sometimes when tests are discovered but not being run.